# Python-pptx for Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, python-pptx

Is it possible to use the pptx (Python-pptx) module for Python 3.5.1? Like for example:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Pt
```

If not then what is the easyest way to replace this module? I think it shouldn't matter for the result but I am using PyCharm as IDE.

I have tried to install it with `pip install python-pptx`. Installing with pip worked just fine when I installed Pandas and matplotlib and other modules. But when I tried to install Python-pptx I got: `ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"`. Then I searched on google but instead only found that it is not possible because Python-pptx only supports python 3.4 or lower and now python 3.5 (what I saw of it)

This is why I started to wonder if there is perhaps a work-around to still make it work. And if not if there are other modules that work like Python-pptx so I won't have to change my whole code too much.

Comment: Does it not work for you? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to install it with pip install python-pptx. Installing with pip worked just fine when I installed Pandas and matplotlib and other modules. But when I try to install Python-pptx I get: ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n". Then I searched on google but instead only found that it is not possible (as far as I could see)

Comment: do you mean "not python 3.5"? I don't see any reason that the package wouldn't be installable, glancing at the source (though they haven't update the trove classifiers in their `setup.py`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences between 3.4 and 3.5 are unlikely to break a package that is already capable of handling 2.7 and lower as well, the differences are not that big.

It sounds more like you don't have the correct binaries installed for `lxml` on which `python-pptx` is dependent. And since `lxml` is only available as wheel for python 3.2 your pip install tries to compile `lxml` from source.

From the message including `\r\n` I assume you are using Windows and for Python 3.5 there is no wheel for `lxml` on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.6.0), so what you should try is install `lxml` from the [unofficial builds from Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) in particular one of the last two, that have `cp35` in the name, from the lxml section [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) (which one depends on your computer running 32 or 64 bit).

After that try to reinstall `python-pptx`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I'm seeing this now but I can say one thing:

My package (md2pptx) uses Python-pptx and it requires 3.8 or later (for the "walrus operator").

So, 5 years and 3 months on :-) , Python-pptx works with very modern Python.